# Time to live property on container

Tags: spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using spring data cosmos db for one of the applications. The problem we are noticing is with the annotation @Document with default values. Having the default values enables the application to create the container if it does not exist with ru set to 4000 and collection name as the model object name except the time to live property on the container. This is by default set to "Off" on the container even though the application sets a value of -1. Is this an expected behavior wherein we have to enable it at the container level on the azure portal?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour of Cosmos DB

> Azure Cosmos DB provides the ability to delete items automatically from a container after a certain time period. By default, you can set time to live at the container level and override the value on a per-item basis. After you set the TTL at a container or at an item level, Azure Cosmos DB will automatically remove these items after the time period, since the time they were last modified. Time to live value is configured in seconds. When you configure TTL, the system will automatically delete the expired items based on the TTL value, without needing a delete operation that is explicitly issued by the client application.

ttl = -1    TTL is disabled. The item will never expire.

Check [Time to Live (TTL) in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live) for complete detail.

Comment: Hey Pankaj,

Thanks for the input! I was facing an issue in the spring data cosmos db library. Reached out to the team, they told me that it was a bug in the project and here is the link reference to it https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/523

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/523, version 2.2.4 of the Spring Data connector addresses this issue.

You can find the release at https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/releases/tag/v2.2.4